# Retrofit & RxJava : do multiple independant request and detect when they are all completed

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

Upon startup of my app I need to load multiple independant data and check if they are all well loaded.

What I do is : first authenticate then send all the request to load the data.
Each call is independant, it is just used to update the local data base.
The call works well.

But how can I get informed that all request are finished ?

```
public static void loadData() {

        LoginService loginService =
                RetrofitHelper.createService(LoginService.class);

        user = new User(ApplicationCore.syncLogin, ApplicationCore.syncPassword);

        loginService.login(user)
                .doOnNext(accessToken -> storeCredentials(accessToken))
                .doOnNext(a -> processData1())
                .doOnNext(a -> processData2())
                .doOnNext(a -> processData3())
                .doOnNext(a -> processData4())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
                .subscribe(a -> Log.d("XXX","*********** END *********"));
    }

private static DisposableSingleObserver processData1 () {


        return RetrofitHelper.createService(Data1Service.class, true, authType, authToken).fetchAll(ApplicationCore.appVersionNum)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<List<Data1>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(List<Data1> dataList) {
                        if (Data1DB.updateData(new ArrayList<>(dataList)) ) {  // success

                        } else {

                            Log.d(TAG,"Error on processData1");
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Error on processData1",e);
                    }
                });
    }
```

In my log I see that the "*********** END *********" is displayed right away after the network calls before the data are received.

I would like to be able to observer when the last data is processed.

Comment: Nice question 1+ vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of options available but pls consider this one (pseudocode):

```
    loginService.login(user)
            .doOnNext(accessToken -> storeCredentials(accessToken))
            .flatMapCompletable(a -> Completable.mergeArray(
                     fetchAll1(...)
                         .map(data->...Data1DB.updateData...)
                         .toCompletable(),
                     fetchAll2(...)
                     ...
                 )
             )
             .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. But where do you put the code to be executed when all finishes ? I was also thinking about using MutableLiveData object to track the state, either failure or success.

Comment: Once all fetchXXX are getting completed with no errors, corresponding subscription handler will be fired.

Comment: Curiously it crashes when login

Comment: Have you added all these subscribeOn/observeOn? I have omitted them in my answer for simplicity. Can be network on main thread crash. More info please?

Comment: Sure it works much better with this obvious additions :-)

Comment: One more question how can I catch errors ? I just add onError() ?

Comment: It works well with all my requests but it seams that the requests are sent sequentialy (one sent after the previous is completed) but not in parallele as it was working the way I initialy did it.

Comment: Yes you can listen to error in onError of your subscription. If you are observing your mergeArray requests executed sequentially, then likely you have issue with concurrency model of these requests. Try to debug what kind of threads each processDataX executes on.

Comment: Adding .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) on each processDataX does the Job. I've tried to thows an error in the json parsing,  the "doOnError" works (display *** ERROR *** in log but the app crashes. See my new code above

Comment: You must make sure there is onError handler in your subscription. doOnError is just plain callback.

Comment: Thanks. All works perfectly well now ! I have updated the final version of my code if it can helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it is implemented now.
Each "processData1()" is executed either sequentialy if no "subscribeOn" in each processDataX function, or in parallel if "subscribeOn" is added.

And then when all is finished subscribe is executed.

```
          public static void loadRefMatrix() {

                LoginService loginService =
                        RetrofitHelper.createService(LoginService.class);

                user = new User(ApplicationCore.syncLogin, ApplicationCore.syncPassword);
        loginService.login(user)
                .doOnNext(accessToken -> storeCredentials(accessToken))
                .flatMapCompletable(a -> Completable.mergeArray(
                        processData1(),
                        processData2(),
                        processData3(),
                        processData4(),
                        processData5(),
                        processData6(),
                        processData7()
                        )
                )         
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        Log.d(TAG, "*********** END *********");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "*********** ERROR *********");
    }
})

 )
                ;
            }

         private static Completable processData1 () {

                return RetrofitHelper.createService(Data1Service.class, true, authType, authToken).fetchAll(ApplicationCore.appVersionNum)
                      .map(data -> {
                                if (Data1DB.updatData(new ArrayList<>(data)) ) {  // success

                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG,"Error on processAcuityMatrix do data");
                                }
                                return true;
                            })
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  // <-- this to process in parallele                   
    .toCompletable();
        }
```